# Business objects frameworks for C# and .net

Tags: .net, business-objects

Is there any other open source BusinessObjects framework available like CSLA for C#?

Comment: What are you looking for in such a framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Business Logic Toolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/) has *some* overlap with CSLA.

Answer (score 1):

The only one I've heard of is the Mere Mortals Framework by Oak Leaf. It's smaller and purportedly easy to use.

http://www.oakleafsd.com/

Comment: I've used MM.NET fora few projects and love it.  Very solid and you get the  full source with the license to extend/modify it however you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what actually you are looking for, but it seems [DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjects.net/) can be mentioned as business-objects framework. This product is designed primarily for business logic implementation.

Yes, and it's actually open source.